# Is it possible to have multiple domain names but one user storage?

Tags: ejabberd

We are using a long grown installation of ejabberd.
We all are using a jid called `{username}@xmpp.foo.bar`
Is there any possibility to alias this host with the domain?

I want, that i can login with baz@foo.bar but internaly ejabberd should connect as `account baz@xmpp.foo.bar`. This would prevent me from migrating all users and have all users to change there clients.

thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the clients to be able to login specifying as JID `baz@foo.bar`, then a DNS query for `foo.bar` must direct the client to the machine that handles ejabberd, and also in ejabberd.yml you must have:

```
hosts:
  - "foo.bar"
```

Then the question is, how to use the existing information? I propose to modify the database content, replacing the old host with the new host.

If you use some SQL database, you may know already what queries to perform. Or you can dump the database to a text file, replace `xmpp.foo.bar` with `foo.bar`, and load it again.

If you use the internal Mnesia database, you can dump it to a text file, modify as I mentioned before, and then load the modified text file.

Comment: thanks for your reply

the dns i have made. but if i only add the new host, then i wil get a new userbase and need to have all my users to update there clients

what i search is to alias this. maybe its impossible?